# How can you distinguish between projections of quantum states?

Tags: specific-reference, quantum-information, research-level, quantum-computer

Consider this problem in quantum cryptography:

We have two pure states $\phi_1,\phi_2$ as input and constants $0 \leq \alpha <\beta \leq 1 $, where "Yes instances" are those for which $$\left|\left<\phi_1,\phi_2\right>\right| \leq \alpha$$ and "No instances" are those for which $$\left|\left<\phi_1,\phi_2\right>\right|\geq \beta$$

I need to devise a quantum circuit that accepts "Yes instances" with probability at least $p$, and "No instances" with at most probability $q$ for some $q<p$.

How can I do this? Is there a reference in which this problem is solved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure whether [tag:research-level] is appropriate for this; someone who knows better, please remove it if that is appropriate.

Comment: This is definitely not research level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a circuit which returns a "1" measurement outcome with probability $\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\left|\left<\phi_1|\phi_2\right>\right|^2\right)$, so this does what you ask with $p=\frac{1-\alpha}{2}$ and $q=\frac{1-\beta}{2}$ (but double check those $p,q$ values because I am short on sleep at the moment).  The circuit is shown on the top of page 682 of [Buhrman, Cleve, Massar, de Wolf (2010), Rev. Mod. Phys. 82, 665–698](http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v82/i1/p665_1).  The idea is that a $\left|+\right>$ state controls a controlled-swap of the two input states.  The control state is then measured in the $X$ basis.  If the states are identical then nothing happens to the control qubit, otherwise it decoheres in the $Z$ basis.

There are also some no-go theorems limiting the possible values of $p$ and $q$ in [Pang, Wu, Chen (2011) Phys. Rev. A 84, 062313](http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v84/i6/e062313), although I haven't actually read this paper.